# Events of TextWatcher are being called twice

Tags: android, textwatcher

On my application I put TextWatcher on EditText. When I change the text of the EditText, the events of TextWatcher are being called twice.

I am using emulator for running the app.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535415/textwatcher-events-are-being-fired-multiple-times

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How does your code looks like? that is the normal behaviour of TextWatcher.
Example:

```
myInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        boolean mToggle = false;

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int s, int b, int c) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (mToggle) { 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "HIT KEY",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mToggle = !mToggle;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int i, int j, int k) {}
    });
```

Comment: yes my code is same but 'hit key' is shown twice when i press a key

Comment: than move the Toast call into afterTextChanged. This method should be called only one time per hit.

Comment: Yes if the "HIT KEY" comes twice, paste your Toast in the afterTextChanged AS Beike suggested.

Comment: Realy? :-) Can't believe that but I have added a quick&dirty solution in the code above. With that your code is called only one times.

Comment: okay i got it am sorry i didnt read it properly... thank you sir

Answer (score 3):

My problem was I added the textWatcher twice `mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher)`, which leads to calling its callbacks twice!

I had added the textWatcher once in `onCreate()` and once in `onStart()`.
I should only add in `onStart` and remove in `onStop()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you call `editText.setText("string")` inside your `TextWatcher` listener (for example in `afterTextChanged` method), `TextWatcher` will detect a new text change, that might end up by calling again `setText` and create a loop.

An alternative to `editText.setText("string")` could be:

```
editText.getText().clear();
editText.append("string");
```

which will not evoke a new detection by the `TextWatcher` listener.

Comment: Triggers TextWatcher for me.