# Is there an alternative to gridview with adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I created a `gridview` with a custom `ArrayAdapter`.  Inside of the `gridView` is a couple of `TextView`s, an `EditText` and a `Spinner`.  Everything was going fine until I added listeners to the `Spinner` and the `EditText`. Aside from the trouble of getting these to work (a lot of issues with the recycling) now it is lagging quite heavily.  I read around and it seems that this is an inherent issue.

There is up to 16 items.  Doing this manually in a Gridlayout or something would cause a ton of manual repeated work, which is why I went with a GridView and adapter.  But the performance issues is a major problem.

So is there a way I can duplicate the functionality of a `GridView` without the issues that I am running into?

If someone thinks they can solve my performance issues with the current code I am happy to post.  It is pretty standard `ArrayAdapter` using the viewholder pattern.  Thanks

UPDATE:
Ok, so I ended up just going with the `RecyclerView` using the pattern laid out in this accepted answer [Saving EditText content in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview)  After some tweaking to my code I have gotten rid of the lag.

Comment: Post your adapter code.  A couple of listeners shouldn't lag your GridView

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a RecyclerView? It is meant for situations where you need to do a large number of calls to repeated patterns like in your gridview. It is much more efficient than gridview/listview for complex layouts.

Comment: I can't speak for OP, but I sometimes I just want a grid rather than a linear list. I've been looking for something to do this, and can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using TableLayout and see if it improves things. You can add all your rows as rows of TableLayout. 
[TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Comment: It appears that the rows would have to be added manually.  Is there a way to add the rows with something like an adapter?  thanks.