# Saving the values entered into EditTexts of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` where each row also has an `EditText` that allows the user to enter a value.

However when the user rotates the screen the values reset to their default blank values.

So I wanted to save the values in a `List` or `Map` so I can refill the list on restore.

However I don't know how to "iterate over the current list" and grab the `EditTexts` and extract the values.

Comment: depends on how many edit texts you have? if few then you should try to save there values in `onSavedInstanceState` and retrieve it in `onCreate`

Comment: you might want to check this question along with solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you take for example the following `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation, you'll notice a few things. The `List` containing the data is `static` meaning it will not be reset on orientation changes. We are adding a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` to allow us to update the values when they are modified, and also we are keeping track of the position by adding a *tag* to the view. Note that this is my particular approach, there are many ways of solving this.

#### Demo

[image]

#### Adapter

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
    private static List<String> mEditTextValues = new ArrayList<>();

    public SampleAdapter(){
        //Mocking content for the editText
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            mEditTextValues.add("I'm editText number "+i);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.edittext,parent,false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = ((CustomViewHolder)holder);
        viewHolder.mEditText.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.mEditText.setText(mEditTextValues.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEditTextValues.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private EditText mEditText;
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mEditText = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if(mEditText.getTag()!=null){
                        mEditTextValues.set((int)mEditText.getTag(),charSequence.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

(gif may look like it's being reset, since it's in a loop, **it's not**)

Answer (score 1):

This is issue for `RecyclerView` recycle.
Just override these function:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
} 

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```