# Android RecyclerView -Multiple Edittext change simultaneously

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that has many cards that hold 4 `EditText`. When I input values in one `EditText` of one card, it fills the same value in random cards. Surprisingly it does not jump `EditText`s for example:

If I input values in `edittext1` of `card1` it would fill the same value into `edittext1` in `card8` and if I change the value in `card8` it will change the value back in `card1`. Could someone please tell me why this is happening.

Thank You in Advance

Here is my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {    
private String[] mDataset;
public String[][] data = new String[30][4];


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     // each data item is just a string in this case
     public LinearLayout mCardView;

     public ViewHolder(LinearLayout v) {
        super(v);
        mCardView = v;
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {

    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}


// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    final EditText txt = (EditText) holder.mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip1_text);
    final EditText txt2 = (EditText) holder.mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip2_text);

    final EditText txt3 = (EditText) holder.mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip3_text);
    final EditText txt4 = (EditText) holder.mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip4_text);
    txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            data[position][0] = s.toString();
            Log.d("DATA" + position + "0", s.toString());
        }
    });
    txt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            data[position][1] = s.toString();
            Log.d("DATA" + position + "1", s.toString());
        }
    });
    txt3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            data[position][2] = s.toString();
            Log.d("DATA" + position + "2", s.toString());
        }
    });
    txt4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            data[position][3] = s.toString();
            Log.d("DATA" + position + "3", s.toString());
        }
    });

    TextView t = (TextView) holder.mCardView.findViewById(R.id.serNo);
    t.setText(mDataset[position]);


}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}

public String[][] getData() {
    return data;
}
```

And this is my card xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="375dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#eeeeee"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="number"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ip1_text"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ip3_text"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ip1_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ip2_text"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ip1_text"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ip4_text"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ip2_text"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ip3_text"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Added to card one]

[image: Automatically it also appears in card 10]

Comment: remember recycler view recycles the existing view(that means if a view is created it will reuse the existing once) so better write condition to clear text\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That happens because the views inside a `RecyclerView` are being recycled. Inside the `onBindViewHolder` you need to set the specific texts to the EditTexts at the specific position.

1. Initialize your Views inside the `ViewHolder` and add the TextWatchers there as the whole philosophy of the `RecyclerView` is to reuse the views :

   ```
   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

       EditText txt;
       EditText txt2;
       EditText txt3;
       EditText txt4;

       TextView serNoTxt;

       public ViewHolder(LinearLayout mCardView) {
           super(mCardView);
           txt = (EditText) mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip1_text);
           txt2 = (EditText) mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip2_text);
           txt3 = (EditText) mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip3_text);
           txt4 = (EditText) mCardView.findViewById(R.id.ip4_text);

           setNoTxt = (TextView) mCardView.findViewById(R.id.serNo);

           txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   data[getAdapterPosition()][0] = s.toString();
                   Log.d("DATA" + getAdapterPosition() + "0", s.toString());
               }
               });
           txt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   data[getAdapterPosition()][1] = s.toString();
                   Log.d("DATA" + getAdapterPosition() + "1", s.toString());
               }
           });
           txt3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   data[getAdapterPosition()][2] = s.toString();
                   Log.d("DATA" + getAdapterPosition() + "2", s.toString());
               }
           });
           txt4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
               @Override
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

               }

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   data[getAdapterPosition()][3] = s.toString();
                   Log.d("DATA" + getAdapterPosition() + "3", s.toString());
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set the appropriate text to the EditTexts in the `onBindViewHolder` :

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       holder.txt1.setText(data[position][0]);
       holder.txt2.setText(data[position][1]);
       holder.txt3.setText(data[position][2]);
       holder.txt4.setText(data[position][3]);

       holder.setNoTxt.setText(mDataset[position]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You updated the data without notifying the adapter. This could create inconsistencies. So after the data is changed you should call `notifyItemChanged()`.

For example:

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        data[position][3] = s.toString();
        Log.d("DATA" + position + "3", s.toString());
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

One more suggestion I have is to reuse the code so you won't have to copy paste so much and fix in many places (for example, all of your TextWatcher objects are basically the same).

Comment: i tried `notifyItemChanged(position)` but now it did not work it just makes my values disappear and jump EditText

Answer (score 0):

I used to OnFocusChangeListener in onBindViewHolder for adapter

```
        editText.setText(mValues.get(position).getValue());
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus)
                    mValues.get(position).setValue(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set data you should use getAdapterPosition() instead of position.
This is because when the recyclerview scrolled, it recycled and the position will not get the correct value.

```
            data[getAdapterPosition()][1] = s.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Issue For Recycler View Recycle Just Override these function

```
 @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  } 

 @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 return position;
 }
```