# Recyclers view edit text content disappears after sliding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with an EditText. When I try to add some value to the EditText and slide down and check the EditText value, the value disappears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving EditText content in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, recyclerview are recycled view. Any view created is not a permanent view, once scrolled the view gets recycled and when you scroll back to the same position, it is created again.

The best way you can achieve this is to save the data (database or shared preference, as per your need) in the method [onViewRecycled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewRecycled(VH)) and to populate that data back in [onBindViewHolder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int,%20java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E))

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save the state of a view after recreation.
just assign it an Id;

Comment: How am new to Android can tell how I can achieve

Comment: just open your view XML file in editor and assign it an id;

Comment: That al are done previously, when I scrolled down recycler view value is reset

Comment: recycler view is working as it's name. it recycle your previous view.

Comment: when scroll down, new views will attach to your recycle view. and when then go up it will recycle your previous view.

Comment: how can i save the value of editteext, i have more than 10 edit text data load from server

Comment: and recycling mean creating from scratch. and if u assign it and id it will restore the previous state of your view . but not your view attached data

Comment: i want to save entired data

Comment: use sqlite database

Comment: i want store only 5 6 sec

Comment: until it closes the page or refreshed

Comment: u can use an array to fetch data from

Comment: how can u help me