# Recycler View Scroll changing item values

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, textfield

When I scroll down and then back to the top, my items were changed for other items in the list, and if I scroll again, the items again are changed.

The edit text value disappears and spinner value changes automatically.

This is my `MyRecyclerViewAdapter` class.

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<UpdateAtt> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mColorNames = new String[]{"Absent", "Half Day", "Leave", "Present", "Suspend"};

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<UpdateAtt> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int i) {
        //View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_attendance, null);
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_attendance, parent, false);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(mView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView tvName;
        private final TextView tvSid;
        private final EditText etRemark;
        private final Spinner tvSpinner;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name);
            this.tvSid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sid);
            this.etRemark = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_remarks);
            this.tvSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> startColorsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item, mColorNames);
            tvSpinner.setAdapter(startColorsAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, final int position) {
        customViewHolder.tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(position).getSName()));
        customViewHolder.tvSid.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(position).getSid()));
        customViewHolder.etRemark.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(position).getRemark()));

        //Setting text view title
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hold the selected spinner item somewhere and use that value to set it back correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `holder.getAdapterPosition()` in `onBindViewHolder()`, instead of position returned by  `onBindViewHolder()`.
Like,

```
customViewHolder.tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(customViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getSName()));
```

Edited:
Set: `customViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

Comment: please put a line of code to where to use getAdapterPosition().

Comment: I have put a line of your code in my answer. Kindly go through it.

Comment: i want mention that the edittext field are editable and when i enter some text  or set a value in dropdown or spinner then scroll it changed the values or dissapears edittext value.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to change your adapter class like the following. It should work.

```
class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private List<UpdateAtt> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mColorNames = new String[]{"Absent", "Half Day", "Leave", "Present", "Suspend"};

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<UpdateAtt> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
        ArrayAdapter<String> startColorsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item, mColorNames);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int i) {
        //View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_attendance, null);
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_attendance, parent, false);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(mView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView tvName;
        private final TextView tvSid;
        private final EditText etRemark;
        private final Spinner tvSpinner;
        ArrayAdapter<String> startColorsAdapter;

        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Name);
            this.tvSid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_sid);
            this.etRemark = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_remarks);
            this.tvSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            startColorsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item, mColorNames);
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            tvName.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(position).getSName()));
            tvSid.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(position).getSid()));
            etRemark.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItemList.get(position).getRemark()));
            tvSpinner.setAdapter(startColorsAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, final int position) {
        customViewHolder.bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }
}
```

And for saving the state of your spinner item in each row, you need to declare an array for saving those state and populate the exact item in the spinner accordingly inside the `bindView` function.

Comment: customViewHolder.bindView(items.get(position)); what is items in this line of code

Comment: Sorry, only `position` should be passed. Please check the updated code.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing now?

Comment: Still when I put some text in edittext and scroll recyclerview the text field text disappeared

Comment: Yes, of course it will be disappeared. You need to save the text in an array when you are putting a text into your `EditText`. Then in your `bindView` function, you need to get the text from the array and set it into your `EditText` accordingly. Add a `TextWatcher` in your `EditText` to get the input values in your `EditText`.

Comment: sir can you please add that code in comment to add text in array

Comment: I would like to suggest you to look into this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860393/3145960. This explains how you save the texts from your `EditText` to an array of `String` and then populate it back while recycling your views.