# Save multiple checkbox Selection in recycler view item with EditText Value in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-studio-3.0, floating-action-button, multipleselection

[image: this is my activity*strong text*]

I have rendered a list of items in a `recyclerView`. When i clicked the Floating action Button, i want to pass the items which have been selected along with the quantity that they have input in the `EditText`. Could anyone give me an example

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving EditText content in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview)

Comment: it's not just saving editText.it's saving multiple editText as well as selected item

Answer (score 0):

Use edit text text changed listener to get the values and store the values as an array.

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

protected EditText editText;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

              editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using some extra variables in model class

```
For example:-
class Model{
   private boolean isChecked; // for checkbox click set this to true and notifyDataSetChanged()
   private String editTextValue:  // call text watcher with editext change and set this variable after every text change in edit text
}
```

View Holder class:-

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected EditText editText;
    protected CheckBox checkBox;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);
checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

          editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if (isChecked) {
            editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(true);
            } else {
 editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(false);
            }
        });

}
```

All these explanation in code is performed inside adapter and then access these variables by getter methods at the time of onClick() of fab button.
For example:-

```
void onFabButtonClick(View v){
        for(Object ob: yourList){
                if(ob.isChecked())
                    { // store checked data here in any list and pass any where you want
}
    }
// pass data from here after store
}
```

Comment: could you please share your implementation with an example application