# Get EditText value from each row in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use `RecyclerView` and `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` for displaying the list of available products to order. Also it will be per `EditText` for each row to input what amount of exact product do they want.

So, how do I get all of the fields from `View.Holder(holder for my adapter)` by clicking on a button

[Image of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiSz2.jpg)

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving EditText content in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview)

Comment: No, it didn't. First of all, I couldn't get how does it work. Also that is made with no FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a list of **Food** model;

```
class Food{

    private String drinkName;
    private String drinkPrice;
    private String editTextValue;

    // getter setter
}
```

Add new variable/property in your model for editTextValue.

```
private String editTextValue;
```

Implement **AddTextChangeListener** in editText for listening content written in editText.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     vhItem.yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                                                   yourModel.setEditTextValue(editable.toString()); }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
     yourModel.setEditTextValue(editable.toString());
    // setEditTextValue is function from getter setter
     }
                    });
    }
```

All editText value will be stored in your model list with their position.

Comment: Can I get value without textWatcher? When button is clicked?

Comment: No. You cannot. First, try implementing it inside Activity then try in recyclerview.Just assume an edit text is being watched, any changes will trigger it.
And Adding value to the model on text changed or after text changed.

Comment: When the button is clicked, how do you access the list of models? (remember it's managed by a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter)

Comment: You can access your list from activity, using interface or you can just do adapter.yourArrayList if your list is public.