# Handling Navigation for EditText inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have taken below layout as a row layout for my recyclerview :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_15"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_dimen_16"
            app:font_type="regular"
            tools:text="day" />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_rs"
                style="@style/edt_rounded_style"
                android:hint="@string/str_rs"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_discounted_price"
                style="@style/edt_rounded_style"
                android:hint="@string/str_discounted_price"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_0p1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you can see as above, There are two EditText in a singal row of Recyclerview.

I have to move next from one EditText to another : Horizontally and then Vertically.

For example if I have written something in first edittext then on clicking NEXT in softkeyboard, second EditText in same row should get focus.

Same way, When I complete entering value for the second EditText in same row then clicking on NEXT, the next edittext in next row should get focus.

**It's matter of navigation between EdiTexts inside RecyclerView.**

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please try adding,    android:nextFocusDown="@id/edt_discounted_price" on first edittext.

Comment: Using text watcher you can do it. But need specific text length for each edittext just like OTP module.

Comment: I hope it'll help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860393

Answer (score 2):

Use FocusDown tag in edittext for navigation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_per_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_15"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_dimen_16"
        app:font_type="regular"
        tools:text="Per day" />
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rs"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/edt_discounted_price"
            style="@style/edt_rounded_gym_fees_style"
            android:hint="@string/str_rs"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_discounted_price"
            style="@style/edt_rounded_gym_fees_style"
            android:hint="@string/str_discounted_price"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
</LinearLayout>
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_0p1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_5"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey" />
```

Comment: This will work for singal row. What if I want to move from discountedprice of first row to edt_rs of next row ?