# Ran into strange bug ,EditText text is filling automatically on scroll in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I tried with empty onBindViewHolder still the same issue
If you can help please drop your answer i would really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

yes, this issue occurs just because it's recyclerview's default behavior.
recyclerview doesn't create a new cell for every view it only creates a view of visible items at a time and then replaces this cell with a previous one while you scroll down.
so you need to maintain their state manually to handle this situation. click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview) for more references.