# edittext in recyclerview is not retaining text watchers on data update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

My main goal is to have a dynamic form like ui on the screen where, the contents of form are changed based on the user choice via a spinner.so for 1 choice, there can be 10 form items of type title-value (i.e a text input edit text) and for another choice, there can be another 10 items of type title value.
in terms of android widgets, it will be a simple homogenous list of `TextInputEditText`s where the properties of each edittext will be determined at runtime (eg isEditable true/false, input type, regex, is enabled, icon, etc). There are mainly 2 problems to solve:

1. The original data/data after user edits should retain when list is scrolled
2. The original/edited data in edittext should be accessible on a button click.
3. points 1 and 2 should work when whole list that is responsible for creating the form ui is updated

Now, I have already checked the most upvoted question and all its answers for a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844373/saving-edittext-content-in-recyclerview) and it helped me partially. With below code, i am able to achieve the first 2 points, but the recyclerview starts showing bugs when we update the adapter's list. I am not sure what is going wrong, but this does not work completely:

```kotlin
//VH
class ETViewHolder(private val binding: EtItemBinding,private val callback: EditTextChangeListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
        val watcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) { callback.changeListener(adapterPosition, s.toString()) }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        }
        binding.etItem.addTextChangedListener(watcher)
    }

    fun bind(etInfo: EditTextDataInfo) {
        binding.tilItem.hint = etInfo.hint
        binding.etItem.setText(etInfo.text)
    }



    companion object {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup,callback: EditTextChangeListener) = ETViewHolder(
            EtItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false),
            callback
        )
    }
}
```

```kotlin
//ADAPTER
class ETRecyclerViewAdapter(private val callback : EditTextChangeListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ETViewHolder>() {

    var etList: List<EditTextDataInfo> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ETViewHolder {
        val vh =  ETViewHolder.create(parent,callback)
        vh.setIsRecyclable(false)
        return vh
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ETViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(etList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = etList.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position

    override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()

}
```

```kotlin
//ACTIVITY
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),EditTextChangeListener {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private val etAdapter = ETRecyclerViewAdapter(this)
    private var listEt = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".map { EditTextDataInfo("$it","$it") }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val context = this

        with(binding){
            etRecyclerView.adapter = etAdapter
            btData.setOnClickListener {
                val text = etAdapter.etList.joinToString(" | ") { "(${it.hint}:${it.text})" }
                AlertDialog.Builder(context).setMessage(
                    text
                ).show()
            }

            ntUpdateList.setOnClickListener {
                val list = "klmnopqrstuvwxyz".map {EditTextDataInfo("$it","$it")  }
                etAdapter.etList = list
            }
            etAdapter.etList = listEt
        }
    }

    override fun changeListener(position: Int, changedText: String) {
        listEt[position].text = changedText
    }

}
```

```kotlin
//INTERFACE

interface EditTextChangeListener {
    fun changeListener(position: Int, changedText: String)
}

data class EditTextDataInfo(
    val hint: String,
    var text: String
){
    companion object{
        fun list1()= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".map { EditTextDataInfo(it.toString(),it.toString()) }
    }
}
```

We have also created a repo for the same issue . here are the steps to replicate:

1. clone this repo https://github.com/sachdeva-tagic/RecyclerViewWithDynamicEditText/tree/master , build the app and run on a device
2. app opens, shows 52 text input edittexts a,b,c,..z,a,b..z with 2 buttons get data and update list. scroll up and down

   - **bug 1 detected : list is slow to scroll (ignore for now, but bonus points for solving this)**
3. press get data >> shows a list of hint and values . change any edit text data and press the button again. >> shows a list of hints and updated values (working as expected)
4. press update list >> will update list to show k...z edittexts
5. change any edittext data (prefer to change edittexts on the extreme ends: top and bottom)  and scroll up/down

   - **bug 2 detected : changes are lost**
6. do step 4 again

   - **bug 3 detected : does not show a list of updated values**

How can i make the list to not stop receiving updates on data update?