# TextWatcher event is fired multiple times

Tags: android, textwatcher, textchanged, addtextchangedlistener

I had a strange error occuring with TextWatcher firing multiple times with different inputs on a single change of text, mainly on entering or removing spaces.

After some investigation I got following results on "afterTextChanged":
Test 1, enter space in String "Suger" -> "Su gar":

1. "gar"
2. " "
3. "Su"
4. "Su gar"

Test 2, enter another space in String "Su gar" -> "Su ga r":

1. "Su r"
2. "Su "
3. "Su ga "
4. "Su ga r"

I've already found a related question suggesting to shut down text suggestions (which I want to keep) or just take the first call (which is plain wrong in my tests):
[TextWatcher events are being fired multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535415/textwatcher-events-are-being-fired-multiple-times)

Theoretically I could just take every event and update everytime because the last one is correct, but I really don't want 3-4 updates in my viewmodel, when one should do the trick.

Has anyone encountered this problem too and has a viable solution?

If needed I can add some code, but I'm really just using the default implementation of a Textwatcher set to an EditText.

Comment: Are you interested in limiting events with an interval duration threshold? e.g. debouncing events with a delay of maybe 100ms.

Comment: I don't think that'd be efficient,

Comment: I've already seen a proposed solution using a debouncer, but if I understood correctly that would get me the first event and skip all events in the next xxx ms. But since the first trigger is not the correct value I might loose the final, correct input which only available in the last event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, any other people who might run into the same issue:

I've just sat down with new energy for this topic and managed to solve it without using a debouncer or deactivating my autocomplete functionby removing the textwatcher completely.

Instead I used a focusListener like this:

```
   int pos = this.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
    et_text.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            updateText(pos, et_text.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

With that in place, I do only get the final result of the text entered by a user, without any events triggered in between.
There still is a slight issue currently, since the User can enter something and then press my save-Button and his input is lost (due to focus not having changed), but that's a minor issue and I'm sure there's help for that, too.