# Text watcher in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a program where i have an editText . I want to implement TextWatcher to reflect the changes in the total edittext. I want to show the alert dialog when editbox reach the max character limit 10. When i implement Text watcher it works but it show two alert box when it reach 10 character. here is my code

```
private TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // This sets a textview to the current length
        // mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 10) {
            messageBody.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SendSms.this);

            alert.setMessage("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                        }
                    });

            alert.show();

        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Add `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to EditText. This will work. Nonsence solution but works

Comment: instead of `AlertDialog` you should use Toast or `mTextEditorWatcher.showError("")`;

Comment: In your XML properties for your EditText, you could add this: `android:maxLength="10"`

Comment: I am with @SilentKiller he is right... better that dialog

Comment: @Gauravkumar you wanna show alert..??

Comment: toast also show 2 times :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is common behavior of this method. You need to handle using flag.***

Use this code

```
   private TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        boolean flag = false; 

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 10) {
            if (!flag) {
                messageBody.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        SendSms.this);

                alert.setMessage("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                            }
                        });

                alert.show();
            }
            flag = true; 
        } else {
            flag = false; 
        }

    }
});
```

---

Other references

[TextWatcher events are being fired multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535415/textwatcher-events-are-being-fired-multiple-times)

[Events of TextWatcher are being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073998/events-of-textwatcher-are-called-twice)

---

Better is to use [setError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). Read [how to use it.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/18/show-error-edittext-seterror-android/)

Comment: No no no. replace your code with this. See what as I updated the code

Comment: woo! thats nice!. Congs.. and one more thing you can do is `s.length() >= 10` instead of `s.length() == 10`.

Comment: sir i want to use test view bellow edittext. that shows that 150,149 character are left. can you help me ??

Comment: Yes sir :).. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013791/live-character-count-for-edittext-android . See they have added `mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));`. Here `mTextView` i the TextView where you want to show count of chars.

Comment: Read above, if any prob say me, will try to clear :)

Comment: sir i want to show. if i write 9 charcter in edit box then text view show that 151 character are left. if i write 29 character then textview show that 131 charcter are left

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42621/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-gaurav-kumar)

Answer (score 1):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
             SendSms.this);
     AlertDialog alertDialog ;

 private TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // This sets a textview to the current length
            // mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));

      if (s.length() >= 10) {
                messageBody.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");
         alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                             int whichButton) {

                     }
                 });

         alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
         if(alertDialog != null  && !alertDialog.isShowing()){
             alertDialog.show();
         }



            }
    else
    {
       mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
    }



        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    };
```

I have editted the code . Globally declare alert Dialog and check whether alertDialog is  already shown and then display the alert

Comment: the text watcher can't be implemented without afterTextChange().

Comment: @Gauravkumar he still has the method in there. Just add it with no code in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

have you tried in `onTextChanged`

```
private TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // This sets a textview to the current length
        // mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));


        if (s.length() == 10) {
            messageBody.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SendSms.this);

            alert.setMessage("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                        }
                    });

            alert.show();

        }

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};
```

Comment: Why should this work instead of `afterTextChanged`? They should both give the same result.

Comment: @Gauravkumar if you type 10 letters it'll show one dialog then if you press ok then you type extra 1 letter then you erase that letter means then dialog will show.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply make the  alert instance global it will work fine.**

```
    private AlertDialog.Builder alert ;
```

in your onCreate

```
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                 RegisterActivity.this);
```

in your afterTextChanged

```
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 10) {
            //messageBody.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            alert.setMessage("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                        }
                    });

            alert.show();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Gaurav in my case it is working fine. Dont put AlertDialog.Builder(
                 RegisterActivity.this); in your afterTextChanged() method

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did such work for phone number, when it reaches 5 digits, it automatically put space. You can utilize my code. Please check below code.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (s.length() == 5 && start == 4) {
                txtNumber.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                txtNumber.append(" ");
                txtNumber.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
            if (s.length() == 6 && start == 5) {
                txtNumber.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                String newtext = s.toString().substring(0, s.length() - 1)
                        + " " + s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
                txtNumber.setText("");
                txtNumber.append(newtext);
                txtNumber.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Code :

**Global Instance :**

```
private AlertDialog.Builder alert;
```

**TextWatcher :**

```
private TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() >= 10) {
            messageBody.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
            // alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            // alert.setMessage("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");
            // alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // }
            // });
            // alert.show();

            // Else you should use the following one to show error message
            messageBody.setError("You Cross the limit of 10 Words !");

        } else {
            messageBody.setError(null);
        }

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```