# Trigger Multiple Times TextEdit onTextChanged

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

My basic code is works, but then i confuse about *trigger*, when edit some editText. When editText is edit or change..

my reference's :

- [TextWatcher events are being fired multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535415/textwatcher-events-are-being-fired-multiple-times)

My input type Xml is number, and i try it. other method is use ignore, and still got same result, stuck. `number|textNoSuggestions`

- Compare to this, [android edittext onchange listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener) my code still make in sense..
- The strange result from this :
  [Events of TextWatcher are being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073998/events-of-textwatcher-are-being-called-twice?noredirect=1&lq=1)

.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValueCrt(holder.editTextCrt.getText().toString());
            if (mToggle) {
                if (mToggle2) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: HIT KEY" + mToggle);
                }
                mToggle2 = !mToggle2;
            }
            mToggle = !mToggle;
        }
```

The first code will only fires/trigger for 1 times, compare with 2nd codes will result multiple trigger at once :

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValueCrt(holder.editTextCrt.getText().toString());
    if (mToggle) {
        if (mToggle2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: HIT KEY" + mToggle);

            try {
                Integer val = Integer.valueOf(holder.editTextSeq.getText().toString());
                if exist data previously, so never replace in seq only
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                //get all data, if empty > set 1, else set : check all data, count data +1
                List<Integer> listQtySeq;
                listQtySeq = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int j = 0; j < CustomeAdapter.editModelArrayList.size(); j++){
                    String nilaiSeq = editModelArrayList.get(j).getEditTextValueSeq();
                    nilaiSeq = checkNull(nilaiSeq);
                    if (Integer.parseInt(nilaiSeq) > 0) {
                        listQtySeq.add(Integer.parseInt(nilaiSeq));
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged: size llistq: "+listQtySeq.size());
                if(listQtySeq.size()<1){
                    editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValueSeq("1");
                }
                else{
                    Integer totSize = listQtySeq.size()+1;
                    Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged: size newZise: "+totSize.toString());
                    editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValueSeq(totSize.toString());
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: error ~" + e);
            }
        }
        mToggle2 = !mToggle2;
    }
    mToggle = !mToggle;

}
```

I want to use that method to execute only once, with some customize code. My question is why my second code invoke multiple trigger, i didn't use loop, or else,,

Thanks for help.

Comment: If there something need more explaination please comment,, or something wrong with my question.. ?

Comment: with is your edit text object?